# jwplayer android live streaming seekbar not shown

Tags: android, jwplayer

I setup my jwplayer in android the stream I use in player is ok because for rewind and showing seekbar it is ok in web with same stream.
but in case of android the very same stream does not show the seek bar so I do not have the seekbar?
any hint or help will really be appreciated

(all other streams suck as VOD have the seekbar and work fine just for live the seekbar is gone inspite of showing the seekbar with the same stream in web)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer, it was a bug from jwplayer